# Are there any ways to do control flow depending on the compilation method?

Tags: compiling

I would like to do something like

```
\if{\pdflatex}{
   \includepdf{file.pdf}
}

\if{\latex}{
  \epsfig{file.eps}
}
```

Maybe this isn't the best example, but do control-flow solutions exist in LaTeX to let us do something depending on how we compile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [ifpdf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifpdf) package.

Although for your specific example of wanting to include graphics.eps or graphics.pdf it's better to `\usepackage{graphicx}` and not specify an extension, i.e. `\includegraphics{graphics}`. See [this FAQ answer](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-graph-pspdf).